# How can I use a regex with flags in a Jenkins pipeline when/changelog?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline stage that I want to skip if there isn't a magic string in the commit message of the form `Release: (major|minor|patch)` (case and some whitespace insensitive) not on the first line. I'm trying to use the `when` directive and `changelog` condition, but it doesn't seem to like my regex, either because it's malformed or literally interpreting the flags `.../im` or escaped whitespace `\s`. I don't quite know how to debug it efficiently...

```
stage('Publish') {
    when {
         changelog '/.*^release:\\s*(major|minor|patch)\\s*$/im'
    }
    # ...
}
```

When it was a "bare" regex like `changelog /.*^`... it had a syntax error.

Is there a way to get the regex to work, or would another solution like

```
when {
    expression { 
        ???? ==~ /.*^release:\\s*(major|minor|patch)\\s*$/im 
    }
```

be better? Not sure what can be dropped into ????.

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy/Java regex flags should come at the beginning and be wrapped in parentheses  like this `/(?im).*^release:\s*(major|minor|patch)\s*$/`.
Also you can get commit change sets from `currentBuild.changeSets`. For git it returns a set of [GitChangeSet](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSet.html).

The following should work

```
when {
    expression { 
        currentBuild.changeSets.any { it.comment =~ /(?im).*^release:\s*(major|minor|patch)\s*$/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't right - you need something like this: `currentBuild.changeSets.any { it.any { it.getMsg() ==~ /(?im).*^release:\s*(major|minor|patch)\s*$/ } }`. Note: nested iterator and `==~` not `=~`